# How to acess a Nginx hosting an angular appp from PKS ingress controller

Tags: angular, kubernetes

I have a docker image containing an angular app hosted on an nginx server. I have deployed this on PKS cluster successfully and  can access this pod through the service having a load balancer. However, when I make service type clusterIP and try to access it through ingress. I get a blank page.

Lets say PKS ingress controller is running on a host named example.com as shown below. Now when we access the URL example.com/ui. I get a blank page though I have mentioned the service and port.What am I doing wrong? How can I get the angular app display for the ingress path? Btw I can access the angular app through the service.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  labels:
    app:  {{ .Release.Name }}
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-ingress
  namespace: {{ .Values.nameSpace }}
  annotations:
    ncp/use-regex: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: {{ .Values.service.path }}
          backend:

            serviceName: {{ .Release.Name }}-service
            servicePort: {{ .Values.service.port }}
```

Comment: instead of sharing a yaml with variables..share the actual yaml

Answer (score 1):

`example.com` need to be resolved to IP of the kubernetes node where PKS ingress controller is running. You could verify this by `nslookup example.com` or `dig example.com`. You could have registered with external DNS provider where DNS system will take care of resolving  the hostname `example.com`  to IP. If you don't have a real domain registered with external DNS provider then you could change the `/etc/hosts` file of the system from where you are accessing to add hostname to IP mapping.

Also `servicePort` specified in ingress should match with `port` specified in the service.